# problem with simple dll in c++

Tags: c++

Hello
i do not use c++ but i try to make a simple dll in c++ by usin Microsoft visual studio 2008 this my steps
1-new project
2-select win32 and chose win32 project
3- from the win Application Wizard i chose Dll   and in Additional Option i celect Empty Project
4-right click "Source Files" and add new item
5- chose c++ file(.cpp)
6- in this file i write this  code

```
#include <windows.h>
__declspec(dllexport) int ss()
{
return 5;
}
```

7-Build the project >> Build Succeeded

but there is no dll file

what is the wrong ??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Where are you checking for the .dll output? By default it outputs to the Solution (NOT Project) debug/release folder.

If you are new to .dll building in Visual Studio I would suggest starting a project in a similar manner but NOT selecting empty project, and selecting 'exports symbols'. By doing this Visual Studio will generate an example file that shows you a good notation for defining exports.

Comment: many thanks i found it the problem was there is to debug folder one in the project and the other in the solution many thanks DeusAduro

Answer (score 2):

Before you compile make sure you set up the buildconfiguration to "Release" and you have to save the whole project somewhere before you compile, otherwise it's located in a temp-folder. After you saved it, compile it and look inside the projectfolder. There should be a folder named "bin" with subfolders. Look inside those subfolders and you should find your dll!